# What does Terry Tao mean by exponential separation

Tags: exponentiation, collatz-conjecture

Tao wrote in his [blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/the-collatz-conjecture-littlewood-offord-theory-and-powers-of-2-and-3/#weak-2) (in the fourth last paragraph):

> Thus we see that any proposed proof of the Collatz conjecture must
> either use transcendence theory, or introduce new techniques that are
> powerful enough to create exponential separation between powers of $2$
> and powers of $3$.

What does he exactly mean about "exponential separation between powers of $2$ and powers of $3$"?

Are there any simple explanations or examples that can be shown?

Comment: See Proposition 6 in the blog post, and the two lines following it. Clearly the separation property he is referring to there is what is stated in proposition 6. Exponential separation is what is stated in proposition 7, where the gaps between powers of 2 and powers of 3 have an exponential lower bound.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - why not form an answer by this? This allows to upvote and "accept" (=close-th-case)...

Comment: @JaapScherphuis What if we rule out powers of two alltogether and use powers of 3 in denominator of the collatz function instead? Ill take a closer looks at proposition 6 and 7. Still a bit fuzzy to me what this all means

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy That makes no sense. The point is that the Collatz function multiplies by 3 (and adds 1 but ignore that for now) or divides by 2. To get into a cycle we need the multiplications and divisions to cancel out, so we need a power of 3 to be close to a power of 2. That is what those propositions are about - finding out whether such a cycle is possible by looking at how small the distance between a power of 2 and a power of 3 can become.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ok. Im a coder, so I haven't understood all mathy things. Ive been probing this problem for many years. I have found some equivalent functions to the shortcut function and the latest function i have divides by $3$ based on parity condition .i.e $3^0$ or $3^1$ even though its not an exponential expression in the denominator. It gives the exact same outputs as $(3n+1)/2$ and $n/2$, but it has ceiling function in numerator and the expression of the denominator is either $1$ or $3$. The result of the numerator are numbers congruent to $0$ or $2$ mod $3$. https://oeis.org/A007494

Comment: ...and it produces the Collatz iterates for the shortcut form of the function. I.e. it will output the iterates based on a division of $3$ or $1$. I will post a new question and explain this when I know more about why this function work the way it do and what kind of questions one should ask about it, because I don't know if its useful for anyone here yet.